# When is the next Yovel?

Tags: yovel

When is the next Yovel (Jubilee) Year?

Comment: This question is specifically about when the next Yovel is unlike those linked.

Comment: As the linked questions make clear, there is no next yovel scheduled

Comment: *WHEN* would it be if the requirements were satisfied?